# WinSock select() on listen()ing socket, non-blocking I/O?

Tags: winsock

When I do a `select()` on a `listen()`ing socket on Windows and it is non-blocking. Do I get a *read* event or a *write* event when there is a connection pending?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

read.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The parameter *readfds* identifies the
>   sockets that are to be checked for
>   readability. If the socket is
>   currently in the listen state, it will
>   be marked as readable if an incoming
>   connection request has been received
>   such that an accept is guaranteed to
>   complete without blocking.